# Different clipping using gdalwarp on Python and GIS

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, gdalwarp

I'm doing some clipping tests with many polygons on different tiles and I noticed that the `gdalwarp` command returns two different clippings with Python and QGIS, could you tell me why?

[image]

```
import gdal  # version 3.0.4
import os

polygons = #path shp list
rasterfiles = #path .tif list

i=1
for polygon in polygons:
    subdirshp,shp=os.path.split(str(polygon))
    shp= os.path.splitext(shp)   

    for raster_path in rasterfiles:
        subdir,file=os.path.split(str(raster_path))
        file= os.path.splitext(file)
        output_path = outputPath + "\\ID_{}_TILE_{}".format(shp[0],str(i)) + ".tif"        

        result = gdal.Warp(output_path, raster_path, cutlineDSName=polygon, cropToCutline=True, dstNodata = 0.0)
        i=i+1
        outRaster = gdal.Warp(srcDSOrSrcDSTab=rasterfiles, destNameOrDestDS=output_path +"\\ID_{}_TILE_{}".format(shp[0],str(i)))

        outRaster= None
```

Command line on sample QGIS:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline ./input_shp.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata 0.0 ./input_raster.tif ./otput.tif
```

Comment: One question per Question, please.